# problem using ORDER BY in postgres with UNION clause

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am trying to run this query in postgresql

```
SELECT DISTINCT users."uid", tax."tid"
FROM tax
LEFT JOIN users ON tax."uid" = users."uid"

UNION 

SELECT DISTINCT users."uid", tax."tid"
FROM tax 
LEFT JOIN users ON tax."uid" = users."uid"
ORDER BY users."uid", tax."tid"
```

but I come across this error

```
missing FROM-clause entry for table "users"
LINE 10: ORDER BY users."uid", tax."tid"
```

however, when I run these queries I come across no problem and the results are as expected :-

```
SELECT DISTINCT users."uid", tax."tid"
FROM tax 
LEFT JOIN users ON tax."uid" = users."uid"
ORDER BY users."uid", tax."tid"
```

```
SELECT DISTINCT users."uid", tax."tid"
FROM tax
LEFT JOIN users ON tax."uid" = users."uid"
ORDER BY users."uid", tax."tid"
```

```
SELECT DISTINCT users."uid", tax."tid"
FROM tax
LEFT JOIN users ON tax."uid" = users."uid"

UNION 

SELECT DISTINCT users."uid", tax."tid"
FROM tax 
LEFT JOIN users ON tax."uid" = users."uid"
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave out the table aliases and refer to the columns only by their table aliases:

```
SELECT users."uid", tax."tid"
FROM tax LEFT JOIN
     users
     ON tax."uid" = users."uid"
UNION 
SELECT users."uid", tax."tid"
FROM tax LEFT JOIN
     users
     ON tax."uid" = users."uid"
ORDER BY "uid", "tid";
```

The `SELECT DISTINCT` is redundant, because `UNION` removes duplicates.